# jQuery: using fadeIn() with .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of jQuery code that queries a page via POST and then that page returns some text that gets displayed on the page. This is the code I am using to successfully do this:

```
$.post(
    "query.php?module=vote",  
    {answer: ans, pid: pid, to: to, page: page},
    function(responseText){  
        $("#poll").html(responseText);  
    },  
    "html"  
);
```

I've tried changing `$("#poll").html(responseText)` to `$("#poll").html(responseText).fadeIn(1500);` but it does not work.

What must I do/change to have the text fade into the page?

Comment: please create a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ using some sample response. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to fade in, the element must first be faded out. Try fading out instantly (0 seconds) then using a callback function to add the content and fade in.

```
$.post(
    "query.php?module=vote",  
    {answer: ans, pid: pid, to: to, page: page},
    function(responseText){  
        $("#poll").fadeOut(0,function(){
             $(this).html(responseText).fadeIn();
        }); 
    },  
    "html"  
);
```

Comment: Use .hide() instead of .fadeOut(0) >> $("#poll").hide().html(responseText).fadeIn();

Comment: I agree with @frank_neff. (Hence my answer...)

Answer (score 1):

Before you can fade something in, you must make sure it's hidden. Try this:

```js
$("#poll").html(responseText).hide().fadeIn(1500);
```

Alternatively, you can make sure the element is hidden using CSS:

```css
#poll {
    display: none;
}
```

Live demo (showing both approaches): **http://jsfiddle.net/n5rnw/1/**

Answer (score 0):

Because Of Element is show by-default, so need to **fadeOut/hide** first then again **fadeIn** the elemet, like this:

```
$('#element').fadeOut(500).html(content).fadeIn(500);
```